# C# Limited times a button can be pressed with pop up showing and streamwriting to a file

Tags: c#, winforms

Okay so I am writing a program and it should only allow the user to click a certain Button a random amount of times (1-25 times) which is generated each time the user starts the program. My code is not working for this, the program currently keeps a totalled Value in a ListBox and when the user hits the "limit" amount that they can hit the button, its suppose to write that totalled value to a file which I already have saved. Also how would you incorporate the Message show when this 'Random number of times' is activated? Here is my code, THanks:

```
     public Form1()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
        private int lose()
        {

        // int High_Score;

        Random rand = new Random();
        lost = rand.Next(23) + 2;
        return lost;
        MessageBox.Show(" you lose");


       }

       private void begingameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
        lose();
        //Begin game button disable
        begingameButton.Enabled = false;
        //The roll button is enabled
        rolldieButton.Enabled = true;
        //Makes the beginning instructions visible
        beginLabel.Visible = false;
        //Makes the other instructions visible
        diceBox1.Visible = true;
        //Enables the start over button
        startoverButton.Enabled = true;
        //Displays a total of 0 dollars at the beginning of game
        int beginTotal = 0;
        totalmoneyLabel.Text = beginTotal.ToString("c");

         }
```

Comment: You don't seem to store the integer returned from lose() anywhere? Also the MessageBox will never be called in that function.

Comment: Your program logic flow is all over the place. You need to fix that before you can think about having this question solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `Random` class only once, otherwise you'll get the same number each time you call `.Next()`.

Assuming the roll button is the one that needs to have a limited number of clicks...

```
private Random Rand = new Random();

private int RollCount;
private int RollLimit;

private void begingameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RollCount = 0;
    RollLimit = Rand.Next(1, 25);

    //...other prep work
}

private void rolldieButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RollCount++;

    if (RollCount == RollLimit)
    {
        // limit reached
    }
}
```